# How to change mtu size inside docker container?

Tags: docker, size, containers, mtu

I would like to change the MTU size from specific container, not at docker host, but any command are working, I've tried:
**ifconfig eth0 mtu 1400** and **ip link set mtu 1400 dev eth0**, but I've got "operation not permited", I'm already root user.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried running your container with the `--cap-add=NET_ADMIN` option? e.g:

```
docker run -it --rm --cap-add=NET_ADMIN ubuntu:14.04 ip link add dummy0 type dummy
```

further reading: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/